# Initializing a blank dbSet in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I'm defining a variable within an `if` statement and then trying to use that variable outside the context of that statement.  How can I initialize an empty `dbSet` outside of the if statements so that the `viewModel` can see/populate it?

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
if (order.type.ToString() == "Rush")
{
    var filteredOrders = db.Orders.Where(a => a.rushID == order.rushID).ToList(); 
}
else if (order.type.ToString() == "Standard")
{
    var filteredOrders = db.Orders.Where(a => a.standardID == order.standardID).ToList();
}
else
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}

var viewModel = new OrderDetailsViewModel
{
    PastOrders = filteredOrders,  // filteredOrders doesn't exist here
    Order = order;
};
```

Comment: You are using the .ToList() method in your Queries. Why don't you define a `IList<order> filteredOrders` outside the if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Order> filteredOrders; // or IList<Order>, etc., as your prefer

switch (order.type.ToString())
{
    case "Rush":
        filteredOrders = db.Orders.Where(a => a.rushID == order.rushID).ToList();
    case "Standard":
        filteredOrders = db.Orders.Where(a => a.standardID == order.standardID).ToList();
    default::
        return HttpNotFound();
}

var viewModel = new OrderDetailsViewModel
{
    PastOrders = filteredOrders,
    Order = order;
};
```

---

or better:

```
Func<Order, bool> filter;

switch (order.type.ToString())
{
    case "Rush":
        filter = a => a.rushID == order.rushID;
    case "Standard":
        filter = a => a.standardID == order.standardID;
    default::
        return HttpNotFound();
}

var viewModel = new OrderDetailsViewModel
{
    PastOrders = db.Orders.Where(filter).ToList(),
    Order = order;
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I tried this and I'm getting an error with the .Where() clause... any idea why?

Comment: My comment was referring to your "better" solution - and the error says that there's no method Where() that supports filter.

Comment: @RobVious: Looks like I found where was the problem, see my [recent change](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14513671/revisions). `Where()` [accepts predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx), i.e. generic func returning `bool`.

Comment: Perfect!  I tried that for kicks after seeing another example and it worked, now I know why.  Thanks again.